# Corollary of Vitali's theorem from measure theory

Tags: measure-theory

**Definition:** Suppose $E\subset \mathbb{R}$ and and let $K=\{I_{\alpha}\}_{\alpha\in \Omega}$ be a family of closed nonempty intervals in $\mathbb{R}$. We say that $K$ is Vitali covering of $E$ if for any $x\in E$ and for any $\epsilon>0$ there is $I=I_{x,\epsilon}$ such that $x\in I$ and $\mu(I)<\epsilon$, where by $\mu$ I mean Lebesgue measure on the real line.

> **Vitali's theorem:** Let $E$ be a bounded subset of $\mathbb{R}$ and let $K$ is a Vitali covering of $E$. Then there is countable family of
>   pairwise disjoint $\{I_n\}_{n=1}^{\infty}\subset K$ such that
>   $$\mu^*(E- \sqcup _{n=1}^{\infty}I_n)=0$$

**Corollary:** Under the assumptions of the above theorem one can find finitely many pairwise disjoint intervals $\{I_k\}_{k=1}^{n}\subset K$ such that $$\sum \limits_{k=1}^n\mu(I_k)>\frac{1}{2}\mu^*(E).$$

Can anyone explain to me how the corollary follows the theorem, please? It is not so clear to me .

**EDIT:** I was able to derive the following inequality: $$\mu^*(E)\leq \sum \limits_{k=1}^{\infty}\mu(I_k)$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $I=\cup_{n=1}^\infty I_n$ is measurable
$\mu^* E = \mu^*(E \setminus I) + \mu^*(E \cap I) \le \mu^* I = \mu I$.

Since $\lim_{N \to \infty} \cup_{n=1}^N \mu I_n = \mu I$ we can find some $N$ such that
$\cup_{n=1}^N I_n  > { 1\over 2} \mu I \ge {1 \over 2} \mu^* E$.

Comment: Hmm. Really nice! Probably you meant $\sum_{n=1}^N\mu(I_n)\to \mu(I)$ because Lebesgue measure is continuous, right?

Comment: Thanks for catching that, and yes regarding continuity of measure.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help! I really appreciate it!

Comment: Glad to be able to help :-).

Comment: Sorry for the belated remark but the conclusion which you wrote does not makes sense if $\mu(I)=\infty$. So i guess firstly we need to show that $\mu(I)<\infty$, right?

Comment: Well, if $\mu I $ is infinite, then $\sum_{n=1}^N \mu I_n \to \infty$ so you can always find some $N$ so that $\sum_{n=1}^N \mu I_n$ is greater than any number you want. So yes, there is a bug in the proof above, but if $\mu I = \infty$ then the corollary is immediate.